# "От()того" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Предложение такое: "Он был в ужасе от()того, что ему предстоит". Не соображу, слитно тут или раздельно нужно писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае "от того что" - это составной союз, который расчленили. От этого там появляется запятая. "От того" в вашем примере можно рассмотреть как предлог с местоимением, поэтому пишется раздельно. "Оттого" пишется слитно только тогда, когда это наречие со значением "по этой причине".

Comment: Противоречите сами себе. Или союз, или местоимение. Конечно, в данном случае "от того"- местоимение с предлогом, а что - это союз. И назвать все это вместе  расчлененным союзом нельзя. Союз оттого что пишется по другому, расчленили - значит разделили запятой. А в данном случае и правописание другое.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь и "что" не союз, а союзное слово, на него падает логическое ударение. "Что" - местоимение, в придаточном предложении у него роль подлежащего.
Попытаюсь объяснить. Сначала цитата.
ПАС Лопатина:"**Но союзы могут расчленяться — в зависимости от смысла предложения, логического выделения (усиления) первой части союза. В этом случае запятая ставится перед второй частью союза, а первая включается в состав главной части как соотносительное слово: Оттого, что мы встали очень рано и потом ничего не делали, этот день казался очень длинным (Ч.)"**
Сравним три предложения:1)"*Он был в ужасе оттого (=потому), что ему предстоит объяснение", 2)"Он был в ужасе, оттого что ему предстоит объяснение" и 3)"Он был в ужасе от того, что ему предстоит".* В первом предложении составной союз расчленён. Первая его часть осталась в главном предложении, на неё падает логическое ударение, это т.наз. соотносительное слово,а "что" присоединяет  придаточную часть с причинным значением. 
Во втором предложении подчинительный союз "оттого что" присоединяет придаточное причины. Здесь всё прозрачно.
В третьем предложении, в первой (главной) его части, "от того" - указательное местоимение с предлогом "от", а в придаточной "что" уже несёт смысловую нагрузку (ср.:"это ему предстоит", "объяснение ему предстоит"), "что" здесь не союз, а союзное слово, в данном случае относительное местоимение, которое является подлежащим. Придаточное местоименно-определительное, и, самое интересное, оно вовсе не безличное, как может показаться на первый взгляд. Другое дело предложение типа: *Ему предстоит пройти много испытаний.* 
**Ради Бога, я здесь недавно, как вы делаете абзацы???**

Comment: Что? ;)))))

Comment: Абзацы - два пробела в конце предыдущей строки.  
Тут где-то справка по редатору была, я вам найду попозже.
Ео вообще он на редкость дурной, трудно объяснить, почему создатели сайта на нем остановились.

Comment: Конечно же, что местоимение. Без сомнения. ПРошу прощения за торопливость и ошибку.

Comment: Ekaterina! Добро пожаловать на форум! В правом верхнем углу написано "справка". Там есть все правила форума и ссылка на правила редактирования. Тоже мучилась...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! С вами очень интересно!

Answer (score 0):

> > > Здесь и **"что"** не союз, а союзное слово, на него падает логическое ударение. **"Что"** - местоимение, в придаточном предложении у него роль подлежащего.

Я так понимаю, что вы спорите с предыдущим ответом. Тогда определитесь, его, ответа, автор таких двусмысленностей не переживет. ))))

Если чего-то ещё помню, то составной союз "оттого что" всегда пишется слитно (первое слово), и в рередине предложения допускает двоякое написание: ", оттого что" и "оттого, что" - в зависимости от смыслового акцента. Аналогично "потому что".

А здесь мы действительно имеет дело с сочетаним "то, что" в родительном падеже с предлогом от. Слитного написания быть не может.

Спутать эти случаи очень трудно, первый допускае замену на "потому что", второй - замену подчиненного предложения на конструкцию с тем же предлогом, например - на существительное. В нашем случае: "от предстоящей деятельности" . Вот, собственно, и все.